# SQL Server inner join to that query again inner join again the same

Tags: sql-server, join

We are working with MLM project. The basic idea of this project is like

- A has been introduced by
- B has been introduced  by A
- C has been introduced  by B
- D has been introduced  by C

My SQL Server table structure is like

**user_details**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcHGd.jpg

Now theoretically

```
A's Team Members are => B , C , D  
    B's Team Members are => C , D 
    C's Team Member is => D
    D's Team Member is => null (he doesn't have any team members yet)
```

Using a SQL query, how can I find team members of 'A'?

Comment: I think your question would be better received if you post up what you have tried - Feels like we would just be doing your work for you.

Comment: Hello, 
Its absolutely not like that. I am not expecting you to do my work. But literally I am not getting from where to start.

I know inner join can be used. 
I can start with 
Select * from 
 (Select * from user_details inner join user_details on introduced_by_id = user_details.ID where ID=1 ) as a
Inner join user_details on user_details.introduced_by_id=user_details.id

But this will help me to find A’s team Till B but how I can find C and D?
Then I have to write more 2 inner join.. 
But really speaking there are 25 members I have find.

Comment: Just speaking from personal experience, people are more likely to help if you have showed you have tried to tackle the problem. Update your question with the code you have tried so far and the problems you are facing.

Comment: k. sure . will update soon

Comment: Hi did you go through my answer? Please let me know whether it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive SELECT statement as follows:-

```
DECLARE @LeadName CHAR(1) = 'A';

WITH Team AS (
     SELECT ID, F_NAME, L_NAME, INTRODUCED_BY FROM mlm 
     WHERE F_NAME = @LeadName
     UNION ALL
     SELECT M.ID, M.F_NAME, M.L_NAME, M.INTRODUCED_BY FROM mlm M 
         JOIN Team T ON M.INTRODUCED_BY = T.ID
)
SELECT * FROM Team WHERE F_NAME <> @LeadName;
```

Here the variable `@LeadName` is the `F_NAME` of the desired root ('A' in your case).